# Check to see if a video loads in iPad with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I am having a bit of an issue with checking to see if a video is being loaded in iPad. I need to check and see if loads because I am looping through to load all videos with an increment like video_1.mp4, video_2.mp4, video_3.mp4. However, it seems like it ignores the "readyState" and goes straight to the else statement.

Here is the code:

```
function loadMedia() {
var media = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

if (media.readyState === 4) {
    alert("Video has been loaded!");
} else {
    alert("Video hasn't been loaded!");
}
}
```

Is readyState supported by iPad?

**Edit: Added more code.**

The loadMedia function is binded to window.onload via an anonymous function.

```
window.onload = (function () {
    loadMedia();
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<video class="video" controls="controls" poster="images/posters/tb_1.jpg" preload="metadata">
    <source src="media/tb_1.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2'" />
    We apologize, but your browser does not support this video. Please consider an upgrade.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple documentation seems to at least suggest that `readyState` for media elements has been around since iOS 3.0:
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/HTMLMediaElementClassReference/HTMLMediaElement/HTMLMediaElement.html

That's sort of indirect documentation, perhaps, but it's something.

Since firing up a JS debugger on devices can be annoying, you might want to change this:

```
alert("Video hasn't been loaded!")
```

To this:

```
alert("Video hasn't been loaded! " + media.readyState);
```

If you turn on the console in the browser (and, if you like, switch to `console.log()` rather than `alert()`), this should tell you if your problem is that readyState is undefined (and therefore likely not supported) or if the problem is that maybe `media` is undefined (seems unlikely).

Of course, you may have also found a bug. You might want to search Apple's bug tracker, if they allow such things.

Comment: I tried that and it said "0" which I'm sure it means "HAVE_NOTHING". I know Apple has a bug reporter but I don't know if you can browse for them.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that and the value is "1". In this doc, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLMediaElement, it says a value of "1" is IDLE. I checked for a value of 3? I maybe writing something incorrect... but it works on the desktop in Chrome and Firefox. **Edit:** networkState doesn't work on the desktop. The value is also "1".

Comment: `1` is fine. `0` would be a problem.

Comment: How is `loadMedia()` being called? Can you show more code?  How long are you waiting before calling `loadMedia()`? Or is there an event handler that calls it?

Comment: I provided more code above. Look at the edit. This has got me in a bind. Why do browsers have to be so inconsistent.

Comment: What happens if you change the call to `loadMedia()` to, say, `setTimeout(loadMedia,5000)`?

Comment: Nothing happens still. It still gives the same errors. =( I can't seem to find any tutorials on creating a video gallery for iPad.

Comment: Let's take a step back. Why do you want to load them sequentially? Why not just have the iPad load them all?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have been trying to find another way around this. The purpose of this application is to flip through videos by clicking on the (next/previous) arrows. It is for my girlfriend as I want to provide her a media app for her iPad and SmartTV. The i incriminator is what loads the videos sequentially when the (next/previous) video is available. The logic behind this system sounds horrible. How would you go about loading all the videos? And I'm not sure how many videos will be in the media directory at one time. They all will need to be loaded from that.